# Find time difference between 2 dates with days, hours and minutes

Tags: node.js, typescript, date, datetime, time

Let's suppose I have a array list with all these following data.

```yaml
let events = {
      ["-1 19:00"],
      ["-1 20:00"],
      ["-1 17:00", "-1 23:00"],
      ["1 18:00"],
      ["2 18:00"],
      ["3 18:00"],
      ["4 18:00"],
      ["5 18:00"],
      ["6 18:00"],
      ["7 18:00"],
    };
```

So, Here -1 represents every single day, Like every "sunday, monday" and so on. -1 = everyday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday and so on.

So, I want to calculate The time left from the current time to the nearest day with hours and mins inside the array. I'm really lacking idea on how I'm supposed to do it.

```js
getTimeLeftTillDay(dayname, time) :any {
        let d = new Date();
        let coming = parseInt(dayname);
        if(coming === -1) {
          coming = d.getDay();
        }
        const day = d.getDay();
        const targetDay = coming;  // Someday
        let dayOffset = targetDay - day;
        if (dayOffset < 0) dayOffset += 7;
        d = new Date(d.getTime() + (dayOffset * 24 * 3600 * 1000));
        let timea = parseInt(time[0]);
        let timeb = parseInt(time[1]);
        d.setHours(timea);
        d.setMinutes(timeb);
        return d;
}
```

I tried to use the above code but it doesn't work as I expected. I'll really like help!

Comment: Can you add some examples describing input and expected output?

Comment: @eol If the current time is Sunday 17:00, Input `-1 18:00` will return `0d 1h 0m 0s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If relying on a 3rd-party library is ok for you, I'd use one of the many date-libs to perform the calculations. Here's how you could do it using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/):

```
import {addDays, formatDuration, intervalToDuration, setHours, setMinutes} from "date-fns";

const getTimeLeftTillDay = (dayName, time) => {
    let daysToAdd = 0;
    if (dayName !== '-1') {
        daysToAdd = Number.parseInt(dayName);
    }
    const startDate = new Date();
    let endDate = addDays(startDate, daysToAdd);

    const [minutes, seconds] = time.split(":");
    const hoursToSet = Number.parseInt(minutes);
    endDate = setHours(endDate, hoursToSet)
    const minutesToSet = Number.parseInt(seconds);
    endDate = setMinutes(endDate, minutesToSet)
    return customFormatDuration(startDate, endDate);
}

export const customFormatDuration = (start, end) => {
    const durations = intervalToDuration({start, end})
    return formatDuration(durations);
}

console.log(getTimeLeftTillDay("-1", "19:00"));
console.log(getTimeLeftTillDay("1", "02:00"));
console.log(getTimeLeftTillDay("7", "02:00"));
```

This prints the following on my machine (executed at 2:25 pm, CET):

```
4 hours 35 minutes
11 hours 35 minutes
6 days 21 hours 35 minutes
```

Comment: It did the work but It doesn't show seconds as well.

Comment: The thing is that you only set hours and minutes to the durrent date, hence the seconds will stay the same. But you can add support for seconds as well if you add it to your template like `"1", "02:00:30"` and then parse/set the seconds using `setSeconds`.

Comment: Okay @eol, But if the input is "15:10" and the current time is "15:20" It'll show "10 minutes" rather showing time to next day's 15:10.

Comment: I've added another answer for such cases.

Comment: It did work @eol, But if today is tuesday and I provide "1" which stands for Monday as an argument it gives me `18 hours 11 minutes` Instead of `6d something`

Comment: Updated the second answer. Make sure to upvote it, if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider cases where the calculated time is before the current time and you want to treat them as "next-day" and handle days in the past in general, you can do:

```
const getTimeLeftTillDay = (dayName, time) => {
    const startDate = new Date();
    let dayToSet = getDay(startDate);
    if (dayName !== '-1') {
        dayToSet = Number.parseInt(dayName) - 1;
    }

    let endDate = new Date();

    const [minutes, seconds] = time.split(":");
    const hoursToSet = Number.parseInt(minutes);
    endDate = setHours(endDate, hoursToSet)
    const minutesToSet = Number.parseInt(seconds);
    endDate = setMinutes(endDate, minutesToSet)
    endDate = setDay(endDate, dayToSet);
    if (isBefore(endDate, startDate)) {
        endDate = addDays(endDate, 1);
    }
    return customFormatDuration(startDate, endDate);
}
```